# Is there anything in django that can determine whether a website visitor has landed on the website using google search or not?

Tags: django

I wish to find out how a user has landed on my website (built on django1.11, python 3.7)? Whether he found me through google search or is a direct visitor?

Comment: You could check the referrer from the `META` or you employ Google Analytics and it takes care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the referrer off the request object.

```py
request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

That should get the referring page if there was one. Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest)